# Having separate cookie storage for two UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview

**Background**
I am developing a simple iPad application that allow the user to browse the same website with different logins at the same time. Therefore I have two `UIWebView` and they should have different cookie storage so the user can login one account on the first `UIWebView` and another account on the second `UIWebView`.

**What have I tried?**
I think the solution is to implement different cookie storages in the two `UIWebView` I have.

Sasmito Adibowo wrote an article [Implementing Your Own Cookie Storage](http://cutecoder.org/programming/implementing-cookie-storage/) which provide details on how to use a custom cookie storage for `WebView` on Mac.
It is done by modify the NSURLRequest that `WebView` is going to send, adding cookie headers to it, and also intercept the response from `WebView` and extract the cookies from the response header and save it to our own cookie storage.
Technically, it is done by implementing these two delegate methods:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
```

Although it is undocumented, `UIWebView` did support one of the method above with a slightly different method name:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)uiWebView:(UIWebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(id)dataSource
```

However, `UIWebView` don't have a equivalent delegate method for `webView:resource:didReceiveResponse:fromDataSource:` and hence I cannot extract the cookies from the response headers.

**The Question**
Is there a way to have `UIWebView` to use a custom cookie storage, so the two `UIWebView` can have their own cookie storage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the cookies associated with a particular webview (and holding onto them) in webViewDidStartLoad:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
    [self.cookies addObject:cookie];
}
```

And storing these cookies right after (retrieve values and keys from self.cookies):

```
NSMutableDictionary *cookieDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[cookieDict setObject:@"value1" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
[cookieDict setObject:@"value2" forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];
[cookieDict setObject:@"value3" forKey:NSHTTPCookieDomain];
...etc..

NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieDict];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:cookie];
```

You'll also need to see this in your viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

Comment: in `webViewDidStartLoad`, the request is already sent, therefore your hack didn't work. Moving it to `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` might work. However, your hack won't allow both UIWebView to load request simultaneously.

Comment: @bdev answer I want in swift 3.0 can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to dig a little deeper, the used-to-be famous [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) knew how to arrange this back in the day. 
Read [switching cookie storage for requests](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#cookies).
 They also have an interesting wrapper for UIWebView requests, AKA [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest).

Sadly, the project has since been discontinued, but it should provide you with an operation ground to achieve your goal.

Otherwise, as bdev has presented, I would queue the requests and replace the cookie storage each time, before firing a request. You could use the dispatcher nicely here.