# Multiple accounts login in different webView in same app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, swift2

How i can login many accounts of same site in different `webView`. For example i have `Tab Bar Controller` That contains three `View Controllers` and each `View Controllers` contain `webView`. And for example i embed `stackoverflow` url for `webView` in every class. How user can login to different accounts at the same time using these three webView? I've tried this but i just login one user at a time. Can any one please tell me how this is possible in (Swift or Objective-C)??
Thanks

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.delegate = self
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }
       func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.delegate = self
        let requestURL = NSURL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        webView.loadRequest(request)

    }
        func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Checking this out might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559441/having-separate-cookie-storage-for-two-uiwebview